# RabbitMQ frame_too_large exception

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I published a message into a queue and consumer is expected to fail to parse the message and put it into DLQ, but the message gets stuck at Unacked state.
The exception I can see is

> ERROR : #method(reply-code=501,
>   reply-text=FRAME_ERROR - type 2, all octets = <<>>:
>   {frame_too_large,206219,131064}, class-id=0, method-id=0)

The message is is actually less than default frame size but bumps up to this big when it tries to drop it to DLQ.
RabbitMQ is configured to default frame_max=131072. If its increased to greater than 206219 works fine and successfully goes to DLQ.
Not sure if it is calculating size of message including exception thrown and other metadata that ends of with frame_too_large error.

Is it better idea to increase the frame_max ? or what might be the better approach ?

Comment: Probably best to ask questions like this on the rabbitmq-users google group - that's where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out.

Comment: Like @GaryRussell said, the RabbitMQ team monitors [the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow. If you post a message to the mailing list, please review [these guidelines](https://github.com/rabbitmq/support-tools/blob/master/docs/Reporting_RabbitMQ_Issues.md) to be sure you provide enough information for us to help out.

Comment: @GaryRussell @LukeBakken thanks for response, i tried google group with no luck. But the issue is exception is too large. The message is including X_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE and X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE into the header and creates large message including payload. Exception is due to JSON parsing at `@StreamListener(queueName) listenerMethod(@Payload content CustomEntity)`. Attempt to sent to DLQ fails due to large frame. Frame_max is default(131072 ). I am using spring cloud stream 1.2.2 release. Is there any configuration to  limit or control the header content ?

Comment: Apparently headers are not fragmented - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

From [this issue](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/135).

> The first thing I'd suspect is that the properties or headers of a message (rather than the content) encode to great than 4k, since AMQP has no provision for fragmenting anything other than message content. Is this possible in your application?

So, since the stack trace is so large; you could either reduce the stack trace size (by catching the exception in your code and throwing a new one with enough information - but don't add the cause), or you can increase the frame_max.

The client asks for 0 (unlimited) but the broker has a limit of 131072 by default.

[Documentation here](https://rabbitmq.docs.pivotal.io/37/rabbit-web-docs/configure.html).

> Maximum permissible size of a frame (in bytes) to negotiate with clients. Setting to 0 means “unlimited” but will trigger a bug in some QPid clients. Setting a larger value may improve throughput; setting a smaller value may improve latency.
>
> Default: 131072

We can consider truncating the stack trace, I opened an [issue here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/159).